# Jenkins Git branch parameter: "ssh: command not found"

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, ssh

Using https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin , when a user in Jenkins navigates to the "build with parameters" page of a build, the list of branches is replaced with

> Command "git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:myorg/my_repo.git" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: /tmp/ssh4348750905358163987.sh: line 6: ssh: command not found
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

When I ssh to the Jenkins master server (which is I'm guessing where the git ls-remote command is being run from) I can run `sudo -u jenkins -- git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:<myorg>/<my_repo>.git` just fine and I get the list of branches.  So why is Jenkins barfing when git tries to call ssh?

When I look at the logs, I see the following stack exception:

> at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1721)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1625)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1616)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getRemoteReferences(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2837)
>     at
>   net.uaznia.lukanus.hudson.plugins.gitparameter.GitParameterDefinition.getBranch(GitParameterDefinition.java:381)
>     at
>   net.uaznia.lukanus.hudson.plugins.gitparameter.GitParameterDefinition.generateContents(GitParameterDefinition.java:310)
>     at
>   net.uaznia.lukanus.hudson.plugins.gitparameter.GitParameterDefinition$DescriptorImpl.doFillValueItems(GitParameterDefinition.java:622)
>     at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:225)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>     at
>   io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>     at
>   io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>     at
>   jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:237)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:214)
>     at
>   net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Edit: If I remove the branch parameter and replace it with a simple string paramater for branch, it fetches successfully so it seems like a bug with the git parameter plugin - maybe when using cygwin/ssh with Windows Jenkins slaves.